# capture line and post it

Tags: linux, bash, curl, awk

there is a log file that I need to capture specific lines in, and send a specific word out of it to a url

This line does the job of tracing that log file and finding that word

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log | awk '/status=bounced/ { sub(/^to=</,"",$7); sub(/>,$/,"",$7); print $7}'
```

Now, I need the result of $7 to be sent to some url, I'm assuming by using curl.
Assuming that this log file will only get bigger and that this script will need to run endlessly in the background..

What's the best way of putting a bash script that will answer those needs?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you've written the script to send that output to your url, you can use crontab to run that periodically.

Comment: What i'm missing is the part to send it to that url.. got a bit into trouble with how to do it.

Comment: Did you mean something like this? [Sending data via post using curl](http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request). You can pipe in your output from awk as an argument to curl, [some examples of what you might use](http://superuser.com/questions/461946/can-i-use-pipe-output-as-a-shell-script-argument), then have that run periodically as often as you'd like by running a cronjob pointing at the script you've written.

Comment: I would very much appreciate it if you guys can help me sort this out into a working bash script :)